# node js async & await functions - force the function to complete?

Tags: node.js, angular, summernote

I'm trying to upload an image using a component (summernote) in an angular form.

I configured the `uploadImagePath` endpoint to submit the image to my nodejs backend, but in my code, the `outputFileName` field is returned empty.

How can I do to ensure that the function completes?

```
async uploadFile(req) {

    var multiparty = require('multiparty');
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    
    let outputFileName = '';

    try {

        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {  
            var imgArray = files.image;

            for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
                
                var singleImg = imgArray[i];
                outputFileName = singleImg.originalFilename;
                
                fs.readFile(singleImg.path , function(err,data) {
                    fs.writeFile('./public/images/'+outputFileName,data, function(err) {
                        if (err) console.log('ERRRRRR!! :'+err);
                        console.log('Fitxer: ' + outputFileName);
                    })
                })       
            }
        });
    } 
    catch (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }

    return { error: false, outputFileName: outputFileName, msg: "File uploaded!" };
}
```

Comment: Please update your question title with more detail to clearly reflect the problem

Comment: Why you set `uploadFile` as an `async` function?

Comment: it is the same, whether you have it or not.
here the problem is that the return happens before the form.parse finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not directly call a function which accepts a callback in a `async` function. This is why your try-catch has less chance of catching any error. Instead, return a `Promise` to handle that error.

```js
function uploadFile(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const multiparty = require('multiparty')
    const form = new multiparty.Form()
    let outputFileName = ''
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      const imgArray = files.image

      // You should not call function that accepts a callback in for loop
      // Lets assumed imageArray has only one element.
      // for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        const singleImg = imgArray[0 /* i */]
        outputFileName = singleImg.originalFilename
        fs.readFile(singleImg.path, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
            return
          }
          fs.writeFile('./public/images/' + outputFileName, data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
              return
            }
            console.log('Fitxer: ' + outputFileName)
            resolve({
              error: false,
              outputFileName: outputFileName,
              msg: "File uploaded!"
            })
          })
        })
      // }
    });
  })
}
```

But as you seen, the above code is messy and the for-loop is not working. To fix this problem, we should make `uploadFile` async, where callback must not be used.

An `async` function should call another function that returns a `Promise` if possible, so that the `await` keyword helps simplify the code and handle thrown error as well. To make such usage, write a new function to make `form.parse` async, and replace `fs` of something that supports returning a `Promise`, such as [`fs.Promise` API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) or [`fs-extra` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra).

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const multiparty = require('multiparty')

function parseForm(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new multiparty.Form()
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(files)
    })
  })
}

async function uploadFile(req) {
  let outputFileName = ''
  const files = await parseForm(req)
  const imgArray = files.image

  // Now we can use for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    const singleImg = imgArray[i]
    outputFileName = singleImg.originalFilename
    const data = await fs.readFile(singleImg.path)
    await fs.writeFile('./public/images/' + outputFileName, data)
    console.log('Fitxer: ' + outputFileName)
  }
  return {
    error: false,
    outputFileName: outputFileName,
    msg: "File uploaded!"
  }
}
```

Still, there is some problem in your code. The `outputFileName` is assigned more than once, which makes your purpose hard to understand. For this reason I cannot rewrite your code that acts as what you are expected.

BTW, more condition should be taken into account. I will not talk much about this.

- It is suggested [not use `var` keyword](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/when-should-use-const-and-let-instead-of-var-in-javascript-ec2c3d7e5ca6) to declare a local variable. Use `const` or `let` instead.
- Avoid using `await` keyword in a for-loop unless you are meant to iterate elements one by one.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to make a helper function which will make nodestyle fn to return a promise, and then use it

```
function parseMultiparty(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) { 
      if(err) reject(err) else resolve([fields, files])
    })

  })
}
```

```
async uploadFile(req) {

    var multiparty = require('multiparty');
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    
    let outputFileName = '';

    try {
        const [fields, files] = await parseMultiparty(req)
          var imgArray = files.image;

          for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
              
              var singleImg = imgArray[i];
              outputFileName = singleImg.originalFilename;
              
              const data = await fs.promises.readFile(singleImg.path)
              console.log('Fitxer: ' + outputFileName);
              try {
                await fs.promises.writeFile('./public/images/'+outputFileName,data)
              } catch(err) { console.log('ERRRRRR!! :'+err);}
          }
    } 
    catch (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }

    return { error: false, outputFileName: outputFileName, msg: "File uploaded!" };
}
```